# Configure user's terminal in Linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Hi I add a new user in my linux mint. But after login that user, some feature losted in the terminal. Such as I cannot use up-arrow and down-arrow in the keyborad to show the previous command. Also there is no color in for different file. Someone could tell me the way to configure these setting? or some link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bash history is user-dependent. You can change the bash settings in the .bashrc file in your home directory, or you can tweak the file /etc/bash.bashrc.